# Force RadioButtons to only change if the bound value actually changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik

I have a bit of a strange case. The issue is that I have 3 radiobuttons and they are binded to the EffectiveValue property of my viewmodel.

```
   <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                            <StackPanel.Visibility>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBoolToVisibilityHidden}">
                                    <Binding Path="IsSelected" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:RadListBoxItem}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="Criterion.IsOverridable"/>
                                    <Binding Path="DataContext.CanOverrideEvaluation" ElementName="ThisInformationControl"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </StackPanel.Visibility>
                            <telerik:RadRadioButton Content="Y" IsChecked="{Binding EffectiveValue, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBool}, ConverterParameter={x:Static utilities:Ternary.TRUE}, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource EmptyRadioButtonStyle}"
                                                Command="{Binding OverrideValueCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Static utilities:Ternary.TRUE}" Margin="2,1" Width="16" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <telerik:RadRadioButton Content="?" IsChecked="{Binding EffectiveValue, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBool}, ConverterParameter={x:Static utilities:Ternary.UNKNOWN}, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource EmptyRadioButtonStyle}"
                                                Command="{Binding OverrideValueCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Static utilities:Ternary.UNKNOWN}" Margin="2,1" Width="16" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <telerik:RadRadioButton Content="N" IsChecked="{Binding EffectiveValue, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBool}, ConverterParameter={x:Static utilities:Ternary.FALSE}, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource EmptyRadioButtonStyle}"
                                                Command="{Binding OverrideValueCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Static utilities:Ternary.FALSE}" Margin="2,1" Width="16" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
```

The problem is this. Say my ViewModel Effective Value is 'Y'. I click the 'N' button. But then based on certain conditions, I do not actually set the EffectiveValue to 'N' and it remains 'Y'. The problem I am having is now the 'N' looks selected even though the viewmodel still says that the value is 'Y'. What can I do to make sure my radiobuttons strictly listen to the viewmodel's value?

My current workaround it to force a property changed on the effective value but I feel this is kind of a hack.

Thanks

Comment: have you defied the GroupName for RadioButtons? I don't have telerik framework so not sure if they have that property .

Comment: @KyloRen It seems like you group them with a stackpanel as I did http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radbuttons/features/radbutton-radio-button

Comment: ok. can you also give your ViewModel code property definition and how you are changing the values. the converter also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer lies with your radio button bindings. Notice that you have them set to [OneWay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode(v=vs.110).aspx), but you said that based on certain conditions you keep the value as 'Y'. How does the WPF control know that you've rejected the UI change?

I suggest changing the binding Mode to TwoWay and maybe also include UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged in the bindings. Then your code behind and the UI can communicate "two ways" to each other about what the appropriate state of the radio button should be.